Why does a zig const reference cause a segmentation fault when passed to C-function?
Consider the following file hello.zig which defines a basic Python C extension (and which works):
const c = @cImport({
    @cInclude("Python.h");
});

var module = c.PyModuleDef{
    .m_name = "__name__",
    .m_doc = "__doc__",
    .m_size = -1,
};

export fn PyInit_hello() [*c]c.PyObject {
    return c.PyModule_Create(&module);
}

$ zig build-lib -dynamic -femit-bin=hello.so -I/usr/include/python3.12 -L/usr/lib -lpython3.12 -lc hello.zig
$ python3.12 -c "import hello; print(hello.__doc__)"                                                       
__doc__


Now, we instead define our module with const instead of var, and we get a segmentation fault:
const c = @cImport({
    @cInclude("Python.h");
});

const module = c.PyModuleDef{
    .m_name = "__name__",
    .m_doc = "__doc__",
    .m_size = -1,
};

export fn PyInit_hello() [*c]c.PyObject {
    return c.PyModule_Create(@constCast(&module));
}

$ zig build-lib -dynamic -femit-bin=hello.so -I/usr/include/python3.12 -L/usr/lib -lpython3.12 -lc hello.zig
$ python3.12 -c "import hello"
[1]    791627 segmentation fault (core dumped)

Why is this happening? Does zig use some kind of read-only memory region for constants, and trigger a segmentation fault if some C-code tries to modify it or something like this?
My zig-version is 0.14.0-dev.244+0d79aa017, and I'm running on x86-64 Linux, kernel version 6.6.32-1
Also, is there a way of doing something like the following inline without having to use @constCast (Since this leads to a segmentation fault)
const c = @cImport({
    @cInclude("Python.h");
});

export fn PyInit_hello() [*c]c.PyObject {
    return c.PyModule_Create(@constCast(&c.PyModuleDef{
        .m_name = "__name__",
        .m_doc = "__doc__",
        .m_size = -1,
    }));
}


Casting away const is a bad idea in both Zig and C - the compiler may decide to place const objects into read-only memory, which may very well be happening here

So what is the calltrace under a debugger? Which function in python source code does the debugger say segfault happens? Finally, why not just assume that PyModuleDef will be modified by python internally and get on wity something else? Do you search for a particular answer to "why"?

The reason I ended up here is because I wanted to pass the struct inline like c.PyModuleCreate(&c.PyModuleDef{...}). And this doesn't work because this inline struct is const, which causes a segfault when combined with @constCast. Interestingly, it seems like if I create the module struct mutable variable inside the init-function, it will just hang indefinitely without returning the module or segfaulting.

There's a good reason why the parameter of the PyModule_Create() is PyModuleDef *def, instead of const PyModuleDef *def. As you can see in the moduleobject.h, the PyModuleDef type is also a PyObject type. So you should not use a const variable for storing it. (See the example of initializing the reference count in the moduleobject.c.)
Just stick to the Python reference for defining a module.
